# Duplicate Classes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am working on an iPhone app and after upgrading to the latest Xcode 4, I received the following error message:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Thu Jan 27 08:34:47 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 3014.
objc[3014]: Class Property is implemented in both /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes and /Users/bschiff/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.2/Applications/7D73796D-01B5-4F0E-A173-E45953945FD2/Versity.app/Versity. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I have a Core Data object called `Property`, and I understand from this error message that a class named `Property` has been declared somewhere else in the SDK.

I also realize that the *proper* way to fix this would be to refactor all of my code to change `Property` into `BSProperty` or use some alternative name.

That would be quite a large undertaking, and before I do that I'm wondering if I can **force** XCode to use the `Property` object in my app rather than the other one that's defined somewhere else.  Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes` indicates that this is a private class, and in that case there is nothing you can do but refactor.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you found an undocumented class (PrivateFrameworks). Unfortunately, I think this means you have to refactor.

Comment: + 1 Yup, ran into this myself when using a class called "Message". There's no way around it.

Comment: There seems to be an undocumented :-) convention with some programmers, especially when producing frameworks, to prefix classes with your initials. Might be a practice to consider when considering names of classes that are common verbs such as Property, message, etc.

Comment: +1 Agreed. For something like this, I don't think you're going to get around it. But Xcode's Refactor>Rename should do most of the work for you.